# SQL Server-Group by

Tags: sql-server

Есть такая таблица состоящая из слудующих столбцов: Id, Name, Price, Izd, Pages, Date, Pressrun, Themes.
Данные там приблизительно такие: 7, IBM PC для пользоватей, 12.00, DiaSoft, 270, 2000-07-07 00:00:00:000, 5000, Использование Пк в целом.

Мне нужно показать издательства и самую старую книгу для каждого из них.
Для этого я использовал следующий query

```
select Name, MIN(Date) as Date, Izd from books
where Date is not null
group by Izd
```

и он выдал ошибку:
Column 'books.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Как я могу эту ошибку исправить, добавив Name в group by ошибка исчезает, но он выдаёт не то что мне надо. Если убрать Name всё ы порядке, но мне нужно чтобы и имя книги выходило.

Comment: пронумеруйте стоки в порядке возрастания даты по группам, и выберите первые, например.

Comment: какая у вас версия slq server?

Answer (score 0):

Сначала надо получить id самых старых книг для каждого издательства, а потом любую информацию по ним:

```
with
old_books as
(
    select Izd, MIN(id) as id
    from books
    where Date is not null
    group by Izd
)

select b.Name, b.Date, b.Izd
from old_books ob
inner join books b on ob.id = b.id
```